# okhttp-urlconnection test crashes mockwebserver, yet passes

Tags: java, okhttp

Run 'mvn install' on okhttp, okhttp-urlconnection, and mockwebserver, then run 'mvn test' in okhttp-urlconnection:

> Mar 08, 2015 11:53:54 AM
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute SEVERE:
>   MockWebServer[51929] connection from /127.0.0.1 crashed
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed   at
>   okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:293)  at
>   okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:289)  at
>   okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.readRequest(MockWebServer.java:555)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.access$1400(MockWebServer.java:85)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3.processOneRequest(MockWebServer.java:482)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3.processConnection(MockWebServer.java:444)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3.execute(MockWebServer.java:386)
>     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Mar 08, 2015 11:53:54 AM
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections
>   INFO: MockWebServer[51929] done accepting connections: Socket closed
>   Mar 08, 2015 11:53:54 AM
>   com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections
>   INFO: MockWebServer[51928] done accepting connections: Socket closed
>   Tests run: 109, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.85
>   sec - in com.squareup.okhttp.UrlConnectionCacheTest

Is this crash an expected result, since the test passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in MockWebServer. We're calling `close()` on the source and the sink in another thread, which is racy and bad. I'll fix.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! I'm finally porting okhttp to iOS, so having a dependable test suite is necessary to keep me honest. :-)